# UILabel in cell only shows after scrolling up and down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a label in cell that I want to update with a data from the JSON array that I parse. The problem is the label is blank after getting the data and will only show after I scroll up and down the tableview. I've tried to force reload the view with `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` and it still doesn't work. How do I approach this?

Here is the snippets of the code with some comments in it:

```
@implementation outletView
@synthesize outletInfo;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:[SERVER_URL stringByAppendingString:@"api/points"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authToken"],@"auth_token",nil] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *outletID = [[outletInfo valueForKeyPath:@"preference"] objectForKey:@"outlet_id"];
        NSArray *outletArray = (NSArray*)responseObject;
        NSLog(@"array: %@", outletArray);
        for(NSDictionary *diction in outletArray) {
            NSString *dictionID = [diction objectForKey:@"outlet_id"];
            if ([dictionID isEqualToString:outletID]) {
                pointOutlet = [diction objectForKey:@"total"]; 
            }
        }        
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error : %@",[error description]);
    }];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = indexPath.section==0 ? @"outletViewCell" : @"categoryCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Here is the cell
    if(indexPath.section==0){
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1] sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:outletInfo[@"backgroundImageUrl"]] placeholderImage:nil];
        [(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:2] sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:outletInfo[@"logoUrl"]] placeholderImage:nil];
        [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3] setText:outletInfo[@"name"]];
        [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4] setText:outletInfo[@"address"]];

        //Here is the UILabel that I want to update
        [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6] setText:pointOutlet];
    } else {
       ...
    }
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: reload the table from the owner of TableView

Comment: try to reload ur tableview [self.tableView ReloadData];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following change:-

```
 [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:[SERVER_URL stringByAppendingString:@"api/points"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authToken"],@"auth_token",nil] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *outletID = [[outletInfo valueForKeyPath:@"preference"] objectForKey:@"outlet_id"];
    NSArray *outletArray = (NSArray*)responseObject;
    NSLog(@"array: %@", outletArray);
    for(NSDictionary *diction in outletArray) {
        NSString *dictionID = [diction objectForKey:@"outlet_id"];
        if ([dictionID isEqualToString:outletID]) {
            pointOutlet = [diction objectForKey:@"total"]; 
        }
     }
       //Here you need to call tableView reload. This will reload your tableView and show the label.
      [tableView reload];       

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",[error description]);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually only need to do this. `[infoTable reloadData]`. Though I don't think my solution is pretty clean. :)

Answer (score 0):

Reload the table on the main thread when you parse the response.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    });
```

Reload the table in this block.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem appear when data not come and your tableView methods call before, reload your table view after fetching all data from server.